# SharePoint 2013 Calculated column issue -Comparing dates

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

Hope you can help me on this issue.

I created a calculated column with the following formula to auto calculate the "Fiscal Quarter" based on the value in the "Date Of Review" column in my list.

```
=IF([Date of Review]<"10/1/2021","",IF(AND([Date of Review]>="10/1/2021",[Date of Review]<="12/31/2021"),"FY22_Q1",IF(AND([Date of Review]>"12/31/2021",[Date of Review]<="3/31/2022"),"FY22_Q2",IF(AND([Date of Review]>"3/31/2022",[Date of Review]<="6/31/2022"),"FY22_Q3","FY22_Q4"))))
```

The "Date Of Review" column is formatted as "mm/dd/yyyy", but when I added a value that is greater than "10/1/2021", for example, "2/23/2022", the calculated column always shows blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check *Date of Review* of Date and Time Format with **date only** option and modify your formula to:

```
=IF([Date of Review]<Date(2021,10,01),"",
IF(AND([Date of Review]>=Date(2021,10,01),[Date of Review] 
<=Date(2021,12,31)),"FY22_Q1",
IF(AND([Date of Review]>Date(2021,12,31),[Date of Review] 
<=Date(2022,03,31)),"FY22_Q2",
IF(AND([Date of Review]>Date(2022,03,31),[Date of Review] 
<=Date(2022,06,31)),"FY22_Q3","FY22_Q4"))))
```

Test result on my end:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, Sir! I changed the date format and it eventually works.